# xlrd: Select cell relative to another cell

Tags: python, xlrd

I'm wondering if there is a way to select a cell/cell range relative to the position of a known cell?
Something along the lines of...

```
refcell = mysheet.cell(4, 4)
desiredcell = refcell.relative_position(2, 1)
```

So desired cell would now select cell (6, 5).

I've looked through the documentation (https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/xlrd/latest/xlrd.pdf) but I can't find anything.

The reason I want to do this is that `refcell` and the surrounding `desiredcells` stay together, but the position of that *block* of cells could change, thus breaking the code. This way I can search the worksheet for a single cell, and base the rest of my code on that position.

Answer (score 0):

```
# sentinel_rowx and sentinel_colx are determined at run-time ... (4, 4) in your example. 

delta_rowx = 2
delta_colx = 1

base_rowx = sentinel_rowx + delta_rowx
base_colx = sentinel_colx + delta_colx

# now some application-specific code
# e.g. operations on a rectangle of 20 rows and 10 columns
for rowx in range(20): 
    for colx in range(10):
        do_something_with(sheet.cell(base_rowx+rowx, base_colx+colx))
```

Is that something like what you are looking for?